# react infinite calendar set the date

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a react-infinite-calendar on a page and after clicked a date, I want the calendar to show that date.

Here is my code:

```
<InfiniteCalendar 
    width={'100%'}
    height={300}
    selected={new Date()}
    maxDate={new Date()}
    onSelect={(v) => {
        //something
    }
}/>
```

I want to update selected inside onSelect but I am not sure how to do it.

Can anyone provide some suggestions?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to set the `selected` prop to the selected date? This is done by design - you don't have to do anything here. However, in case you need the selected date to be returned, simply give the onSelect prop something like `(date) => { console.log(date); }`

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Yes I am trying to set selected props as the date chosen by user but I don't know how should I achieve it

Comment: Right, but why would you want to do that? The `selected` prop is used to set an initially selected date.. If you want to set this, you have to do this outside of the component and re-render it once it changes..

Answer (score 1):

Add dates array to your state

```
state = {
  dates: []
};
```

Then add Array Remover function to your class

```
function arrayRemove(arr, value) {
  return arr.filter(function (ele) {
    return ele != value;
  });
}
```

Then add onSelect function to your InfiniteCalendar

```
     <InfiniteCalendar
       Component={MultipleDatesCalendar}
       interpolateSelection={defaultMultipleDateInterpolation}
       selected={this.state.dates}
       onSelect={(date) => {
         var converted =  date.toLocaleString('default', { weekday: 'short' }) 
                      + ' ' + date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' }) 
                      + ' ' + date.getDate() + ' ' +date.getFullYear() + ' 00:00:00';

       if (!this.state.dates.includes(converted)) {
         this.setState({
           dates: [...this.state.dates, converted]
         })

        return converted;

       } else {
         var result = arrayRemove(this.state.dates, converted);

        this.setState({
          dates: result
        })
    }
  }
} />
```

Then use your state to display selected date

```
<ol>
   {this.state.dates.map((date) => {
     return <li>{date}</li>
   })}
</ol>
```